# In VS2008, for FTP Publishing of a website, is there a way to save FTP Logon password?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, security, authentication, ftp, publishing

I like the Visual Studio 2008 IDE integrated (not command line) feature to choose to publish an ASP.NET website to my webserver via FTP.  I'm able to store my FTP username but I don't see any option to store my FTP password and so I must type it in each time I publish.

Is there an equivalent to the "Remember password" functionality found on many login systems for VS2008 FTP publishing?

[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7752/logino.jpg](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7752/logino.jpg)

Thanks!

Answer (score 41, accepted):

On the previous screen where you select what ftp server you want, simply add the credentials as if you were visiting a secure website in a web browser:

> ftp://myuser:mypass@example.com:21/my/path/to/web/root/

It saves the URL between sessions and does not prompt for passwords, at least in my experience with VS 2008.

Comment: you made my day! (also the stackoverflow similar post suggest :P )

Answer (score 0):

If you want Visual Studio to remember your ftp password, open it as administrator and enable the passive mode.