# Visual Studio keeps asking the FTP password when publishing with ClickOnce

Tags: visual-studio, ftp, clickonce, publishing

I publish my application on a FTP server. I gave the FTP account information  (URL, user and password) to Visual Studio but it keep asking me the FTP password each time I click the *Publish now* button.

Why VS doesn't automatically fullfill my password?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In VS2008, for FTP Publishing of a website, is there a way to save FTP Logon password?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308541/in-vs2008-for-ftp-publishing-of-a-website-is-there-a-way-to-save-ftp-logon-pas)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Response to your question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308541/in-vs2008-for-ftp-publishing-of-a-website-is-there-a-way-to-save-ftp-logon-pass) This was asked another question.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio does not retain the information that you put in, probably so they don't have to do security around it.

Comment: ftp://myuser:mypass@example.com:21/my/path/to/web/root/

it do, but you need to understand how ftp work.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking for VS2012, when you click the 'Edit Publish Profiles' gear icon, it normally opens to the 'Preview' tab (see the left side).  You can then click 'Connection' on the left and add your password.  Then click 'Validate Connection'.  Then click 'Close' and it will prompt you to save the updated profile.

Comment: You're talking about 'one click web publishing', and the question is about 'ClickOnce' which is not the same thing.